# What is the difference between xmap vs pmap as the parallel processing model?

Tags: jax

Can anyone help me understand the similarities and differences between the [xmap](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.experimental.maps.xmap.html) and [pmap](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.pmap.html) in JAX? Read through the documentation multiple times, but still cannot understand the new concepts in the tutorials.

I am specifically interested in if there are any examples for how to convert pmap train setup to xmap train setup.

It seems to me that: mesh+xmap can do similar things as pmap. Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pmap` is a simple parallelizing transform that only supports distribution of data over a single leading axis. It is deprecated, and will likely be removed in a future version of JAX.

`xmap` is a generalization of `pmap` that allows for more flexible parallelization over multiple named axes. It has always been experimental, and will likely be removed in a future version of JAX.

The best way to do parallel computation in JAX going forward is either implicitly via sharded inputs into `jit`, or explicitly via `shard_map`. Unfortunately, neither of these approaches is very well documented at the moment; there is some information at [Distributed Arrays and Automatic Parallelization](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Distributed_arrays_and_automatic_parallelization.html) and [`shard_map` for simple per-device code](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jep/14273-shard-map.html) but both are written more for developers than for end-users. That said, more comprehensive docs for the newer parallelism models in JAX are currently in progress, and should be on the website soon.

Comment: (Oh, I saw your youtube video on JAX!) What I don't understand is, if I shard the data onto the devices (say, 8 GPUs) via mesh (code example: # Data will be split along the batch axis
data_mesh = Mesh(devices, axis_names=("batch",))  # naming axes of the mesh
data_sharding = NamedSharding(
    data_mesh,
    P(
        "batch",
    ),
)  ), will it has the same effect or computation speed as using pmap?

Comment: Sorry, comment threads aren't a great place to discuss multi-line code blocks.

Comment: Got it. Could you let me know if there is any JAX tutorial on how to train or fine tune a LLM with shard_map? (something similar to this tutorial will be great: https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification_flax.ipynb#scrollTo=QOHBpZulqSLT; this tutorial used pmap function; I'd like to know how to implement the same thing with shard_map). Thank you!